# How can I use the Amazon Web Services Plugin for WordPress to do file operations on my S3 bucket

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hook

I want to access my S3 bucket, and when I remove a file, use the [`delete_attachment`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/delete_attachment/) hook to call to Amazon and delete those files ( we have a service that offloads files to S3 but doesn't delete them.

I've installed the [Amazon Web Services](https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-web-services/#installation) plugin for WordPress but I'm not sure where to go from here.

Given a filename, I can remove it from the command line:

```
aws s3 rm s3://BUCKET/DIRECTORY/wp-content/uploads/2018/FILENAME.JPG
```

But I need to do this from PHP.

Say the file being deleted is:

```
https://example.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/file1234.png
```

Then I have the following code that runs on delete:

```
// define the delete_attachment callback 
function action_delete_from_amazon( $id ) { 
    $location = get_the_guid( $id ); // gets that url above
    $s3_filename = $bucket_name . strstr('/wp-content', $location )

    //
    // Call the Amazon S3 service here and 
    // delete all variations of the file...
    //

}; 

// add the action 
add_action( 'delete_attachment', 'action_delete_from_amazon', 10, 1 );
```

Comment: Amazon have really [good docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/DeletingOneObjectUsingPHPSDK.html) for their PHP SDK.

Comment: @fubar Yeah, I found that page. I’m just not sure where to integrate that for a WordPress site.

Comment: A good place to start would be to find how uploads are being pushed to the S3 server from WordPress, because if there is already an SDK integration, you could just leverage the existing implementation.

Comment: @fubar yeah, I have no control over how they're being pushed. It's done as part of the package on WPEngine's LargeFS service.